IAP-enforcing load balancer to single backend to NGINX to applications, or load balancer to several backends to applications?

Everything's on GCP
Various tools and applications are accessed via Cloud Run instances
These should all be protected by IAP + IAM, so a Load Balancer's set up w/ appropriate backend configuration
I'd like for my (generally, Flask app. + frontend) tools and applications to be as unaware of the more-general URL structure as possible. (i.e., one might ping https://domain.name/app1 which routes to the appropriate Cloud Run instance. That instance might request something from /static—but /static needs to be rerouted as https://domain.name/app1/static instead of https://domain.name/static


As far as I can tell, there are maybe two obvious ways of doing  this?

A single GCP backend that points to NGINX. Accessing the given URL is protected by IAP. NGINX then pings Google's metadata server for a token (the IAM part) and routes the request + token to the appropriate Cloud Run instance. The NGINX will have rules that proxy requests like /static back to app1/static based on http_referrer.
Skip NGINX alltogether. Each Cloud Run instance has a GCP backend associated w/ it and the Load Balancer does the routing (the problem w/ this is that I don't know how to perform the above-described routing).

Tools and applications are added, removed, and changed frequently. I want the application-code to be as unaware of the URL structure as possible. I like (2) a lot more, especially since, in (1), the NGINX instance becomes a single point of failure.
Alternatively maybe the best way really is (2) and just have {base}/static in each application. But I would really like to e.g. move an app. from in_dev/app1 to tools/app1 w.o. having to change a base_URL in the application code.

To achieve this, you need to utilize the URL rewrites of the load balancer. This will allow you to change host, path, or both of them before directing traffic to your backend services.
Assuming everything is already set up, you just need to edit the routing rules of your load balancer.

Edit the load balancer and select Routing Rules.

In the mode section, select “Advanced host and path rules”.

On the YAML file, create a “rouetRules” with “matchRules” for your URL request that will distinguish your backend service.

Indicate your desired path by creating “urlRewrite” with “pathPrefixRewrite”.


Sample YAML code below:
name: matcher
routeRules:
- description: service
  matchRules:
  - prefixMatch: /bar                 # Request path that need to be rewrite.
  priority: 1
  service: projects/example-project/global/backendServices/<your-backend>
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathPrefixRewrite: /foo/bar      # This will be your desired path.

For a more comprehensive guide, you can follow this article.

This is close, but not what I need. Going from /service-a to / is easy enough, but if I have two backend's, each of which reference a /static, I need the load balancer to know that the /static from one the first backend goes to its respective backend, and the entirely different /static from the second backend goes to its respective backend
